# Webdriverio Error works on mac and linux but not on Window10

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I can't get my script to run on windows machine. It works fine on linux and mac.
webdriverio v7.7.2

node v15.0.1

npm v7.0.5

Windows 10

```
"scripts": {
    "dubug": "node ./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./configs/debug.conf.js",
}
```

Error message

```
    npm run dubug

> e2e@1.0.0 dubug
> node ./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./configs/debug.conf.js

C:\Users\Puter\Desktop\Aa\aa-client-v2-master\aa-client-v2-master\tests\node_modules\.bin\wdio:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1047:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1112:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:948:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:789:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:72:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Puter\Desktop\Aa\aa-client-v2-master\aa-client-v2-master\tests
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "node ./node_modules/.bin/wdio ./configs/debug.conf.js"
```

Comment: `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")` I am not sure of what this performs from the error pasted but this might not work since on windows, we will have to use a different way for it. Check out `https://www.lemoda.net/windows/windows2unix/windows2unix.html` which gives a list of commands

Comment: I guess that to maybe forget concatenation with + operator